# How can i include server/app.js in webpack-dev-server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a client with `react` and am running `npm start` and in `package.json` my scripts look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  }
```

But i've also code other server side code in `server/app.js` that I want to run and if I run `node app.js` then that runs but i'd like `server/app.js` to be included with `webpack-dev-server` so that when I run `npm start server/app.js` is also run.

Is that possible? I was reading up on the various options and at this stage after the simplest.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your script as follows:

```
"scripts": { 
     "start": "webpack-dev-server && node app.js"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is where I'm a bit confused. In my server folder i've got app.js and a test.html page and when I run "node app.js" I can load test.html and the server scripts in app.js run and the websocket connects. But when I also run webdev-server-pack && node app.js I keep getting the same error message that the websocket is connecting but it actually never does. Been reading up all day on it but not sure where the prob lies. Thx.